# Angular JS 2 - Error during evaluation of click

Tags: scripting

I am following a tutorial in Udemy on Angular JS and facing this problem.

My app.component.ts code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
import {AuthorComponent} from './author.component'
import {FavouriteComponent} from './favourite.component'
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
            <h1>Hello Kuttu</h1><courses></courses><authors></authors>
            <fav></fav>
            `,
directives: [CoursesComponent,AuthorComponent,FavouriteComponent]    
})
export class AppComponent {      
}
```

my favourite component code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
@Component({
selector: 'fav',
template: `
        <i
            class="glyphicon"
            [class.glyphicon-star-empty]="!isFavourite"
            [class.glyphicon-star]="isFlag" 
            (click)="onBClick()"
        >
        </i>
        `
})
export class FavouriteComponent(){
isFavourite = false;
onBClick(){
    this.isFavourite = !this.isFavourite;
}
}
```

The star is rendered in the view and when i click, i am getting the exception

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
angular2.dev.js:23083 EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23094
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made a stupid mistake

FavouriteComponent(){

had a () in the class name and since my editor is not something which can do compilation, i missed this error.